# C+ Array of struct throws error that the types are incomplete (Linux command options parsing)

Tags: c++

I have the following `array[]` struct:

```
const struct options long_options[4] = {
    { "help", 0, NULL, "h" },
    { "output", 1, NULL, "o" },
    { "verbose", 0, NULL, "v" },
    { NULL,  0, NULL, NULL }
};
```

But it (CodeBlocks on Linux) throws this error:

```
elements of array ‘const options long_options [4]’ have incomplete type|
```

How should I solve this error?

### UPDATE

I want to pass it to `getopt_long()` in `getopt.h` for Linux command parsing.

So, I have already: `#include <getopt.h>`

Comment: Did you include the header for `struct options`? It seems you have only forward-declared it

Comment: Is `struct options` actually defined? You need a `struct options { ... };` to define what options look like before you declare array `long_options`

Comment: No I haven't defined anything than this.  Can you please a little explain?

Comment: You need to include the header file that has the definition of "options".

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your code should have `struct option` rather than `struct options`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know what the `struct options` look like, so you need to tell it.

It seems like you're trying to use `getopt_long()`. If this is true, to solve your issue you simply need to add `#include <getopt.h>` to the top of your file. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html)

Inside `getopt.h` there is a declaration that goes something like this

```
struct option {
    const char *name;
    int has_arg;
    int *flag;
    int val;
};
```

so when you `#include` it, the compiler knows what struct option looks like and is able to initialize your array.

**EDIT:** I missed the typo on your original post. The first line of the code you posted should be

```
const struct option long_options[4] = ...
```

rather than

```
const struct options long_options[4] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much. What a bad typo I had